# How to validate a select box in jquery-validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

How can I check for a selected box in a multiple form? My first option is `<option selected disabled hidden style="display:none" value="default"></option>`

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6Tkn/91/

It validates only the input field although the select box have a required attribute.

And how can I check for validation when I click the alert button? In this example I have to fill the input then click send button and then the alert button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
        $('#test').on('click', function() {
          alert('valid form'); //should simulate a next button for multi step form
        });
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" minlength="3" required="required" />
  <select id="selectCatalog" name="selectCatalog" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled hidden style="display:none" value="default" required="required"></option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="email" required="required">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<button id="test">Alert</button>
```

Comment: Set `value=""` on the first option instead of `value="default"` and put `required="true"` on the `select` instead of the `option`. Your code should then work as it is

Comment: do you know how can i validate the input field and select box and show alert in one ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `$.validator.addMethod` if you want to target the input and select dropdown.

```
$.validator.addMethod("validOrNah", function(value, element) {


  if ($("#username").val() === "" || $("#selectCatalog")[0].selectedIndex === 0) {
    return false;
  } 
    return true;

}, "Please enter in text and select dropdown");

$(this).validate({
  rules: {
    selectCatalog: {
      validOrNah: true
    }
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/K6Tkn/129/